# How to make multiple FetchRequests in one view (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to work on a school project and I'm having trouble understanding how to fetch multiple specific sets of data.

I have a view called GameView in which I have the following FetchRequest:

```
FetchRequest(entity: Player.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isPlaying == %@", true))
var allPlayers: FetchedResults<Player>
```

"Player" is a Core Data Entity that has the attributes `firstName`, `lastName`, `Position` and `isPlaying`

However, I need to be able to assign specific roles to specific players based on their position attributes. For example, I want to assign every Player entity that has the position attribute 'P' to a `@State` array for 'Pitchers' and I want to assign every Player entity with a position attribute 'SS' to a `@State` array for 'shortstops'.

The only thing I thought of was making two separate fetch requests with two different predicates but I recall that you can only make one fetch request per view. How can I work around this?

Here's some of the code I have. Previously, I was assigning positions using an Observable Object, but I wanna swap it up.

```
struct GameView: View {
    @ObservedObject var TeamNamesAndColors: TeamAttributes
    // declares all the different variables necessary to represent game state
    @State var GameIsOver: Bool = false
    @State var ProceedToResults: Bool = false
    @State var IsInningTop: Bool = true
    @State var InningNumber: Int = 1
    @State var CurrentBatter: [String: String] = ["FirstName": "", "LastName": "", "Position": ""]
    @State var HitterIndexHome: Int = 1
    @State var HitterIndexAway: Int = 1
    @State var AwayPitcher: [String: String] = ["FirstName": "", "LastName": ""]
    @State var HomePitcher: [String: String] = ["FirstName": "", "LastName": ""]
    @State var CurrentPitcher: [String: String] = ["FirstName": "", "LastName": "", "Position": ""]
    @State var BSOCount: [String: Int] = ["Balls": 0, "Strikes": 0, "Outs": 0]
    @State var BasesState: [String: Bool] = ["1B": false, "2B": false, "3B": false]
    @State var AwayTeamScore: Int = 0
    @State var HomeTeamScore: Int = 0
    // used to present different navigation buttons or Pitch Sheet
    @State var showPitchView = false
    @State var goBackHome = false
    @State var finishEarly = false
    
    // checks which position in the lineup is the pitcher, and assigns it the pitcher role
    func SetAwayPitcher() {
        if AnHDetails.Hitter1APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter1AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter1ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter2APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter2AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter2ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter3APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter3AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter3ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter4APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter4AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter4ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter5APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter5AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter5ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter6APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter6AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter6ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter7APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter7AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter7ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter8APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter8AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter8ALast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter9APos == "P" {
            AwayPitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter9AFirst
            AwayPitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter9ALast
        }
    }
    // same thing as previous func
    func SetHomePitcher () {
        if AnHDetails.Hitter1HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter1HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter1HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter2HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter2HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter2HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter3HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter3HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter3HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter4HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter4HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter4HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter5HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter5HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter5HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter6HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter6HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter6HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter7HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter7HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter7HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter8HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter8HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter8HLast
        } else if AnHDetails.Hitter9HPos == "P" {
            HomePitcher["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter9HFirst
            HomePitcher["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter9HLast
        }
    }
    // decides batter's position and initializes CurrentBatter
    func SetFirstHitter() {
        CurrentBatter["FirstName"] = AnHDetails.hitter1AFirst
        CurrentBatter["LastName"] = AnHDetails.hitter1ALast
        CurrentBatter["Position"] = AnHDetails.Hitter1APos
    }
    // sets the HomePitcher to be the active pitcher to begin the game
    func SetFirstPitcher() {
        CurrentPitcher["FirstName"] = HomePitcher["FirstName"]
        CurrentPitcher["LastName"] = HomePitcher["LastName"]
    }
```

Comment: We are going to need some code on this, but generally, you don't need to put CoreData attributes into separate arrays to use them like you want.

Comment: Oh, alright. How would I identify them otherwise? Once I've fetched the results, how can I access some specific ones?

Comment: `.filter` is one way.

Comment: I'm confused. Let's say I have the following:

 func SetFirstHitter() {
        CurrentBatter["FirstName"] =
        CurrentBatter["LastName"] = 
        CurrentBatter["Position"] = 
    }

If I want to pick out someone from the fetched results I mentioned earlier, how would I do that?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I've added the inital part of my code, minus the FetchRequest. Please let me know how I can integrate core data here, thank you !

Comment: I avoided this originally because you are using CoreData, but please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The problem with what code you have posted is simply that it is a set of brute force functions to filter certain players. However, the code that is needed to answer your question is the `var body` code that shows how you want to use it. Are you modifying the attributes or just displaying them? We can't help you this way.

Comment: Why can you only have one fetch request per view?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Er, I'm not sure. It's what my teacher said...

Comment: Use sectioned fetch request

Comment: I suspect the assignment says to only use one FetchRequest. We can toss out suggestions all we want, but without knowing what the assignment is to achieve, we are just guessing.

Comment: I just have to try and implement the four components of Core Data (CRUD) but I'd evidently bitten off more than I could chew with this kind of project.

I appreciate everyone's help but I'm only more confused now than I was before, I suppose starting from scratch is the way to go.

I'll report back in a while

Comment: You don't need to put _everything_ into a View. A View should just render a (simple) thing. This also includes not to perform FetchRequests - not even a single one. Those parts belong to the "Model".  So, the preferable solution wouldn't use any `@State` variable and not a single `if` in the View implementation. Just introduce a "Model", and cleanly implement the data aspect there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using two ForEach for sections inside of a List (iOS 15):

```
struct TwoFetchedRequests: View {
    // #1
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.sort, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    // #2
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Favorite.sort, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var favorites: FetchedResults<Favorite>

    var body: some View {
       List {
           // #1
           Section {
               ForEach(items) { item in
                   Text(item.fullName)
               }
           } header: {
               Text("Items")
           }
           
           // #2
           Section {
               ForEach(favorites) { fav in
                   Text(fav.fullName)
               }
           } header: {
               Text("Favorites")
           }
        }
    }
}
```